# igraph: why is add_edge function so slow ompared to add_edges?

Tags: python, igraph

i am surprised that:

```
import igraph
import random, time
start_time = time.time()
G = igraph.Graph(directed = True)
G.add_vertices(10000)
for i in range(30000):
   G.add_edge(random.randint(0,9999), random.randint(0,9999))
print "done in " + str(int(time.time() - start_time)) + " seconds"
```

returns done in 63 seconds

while

```
import igraph
import random, time
start_time = time.time()
G = igraph.Graph(directed = True)
G.add_vertices(10000)
edges = []
for i in range(30000):
    edges += [(random.randint(0,9999), random.randint(0,9999))]
G.add_edges(edges)
print "done in " + str(int(time.time() - start_time)) + " seconds"
```

returns done in 0 seconds.
Does someone from the project know why?

Comment: On the [igraph page](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc-0.5/html/ch04s02s03.html) it says: _Note that if you want to add many edges to a big graph, then it is unefficient to add them one by one, it is better to collect them into a vector and add all of them via a single igraph_add_edges() call._ I could imagine that updating a big number of entries in the AM at once (and returning the graph object once) is faster than updating a single entry a large number of times and returning the graph object each time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason is that igraph uses an indexed edge list as its data structure in the C layer. The index makes it possible to query the neighbors of a specific vertex in constant time. This is good if your graph rarely changes, but it becomes a burden when the modification operations are far more frequent than the queries, since whenever you add or remove an edge, you have to update the index. So, every call to `add_edge` will make igraph reindex its internal data structures. The upside is that if you have to rebuild the index anyway, you can just as well add many edges using `add_edges` with approximately the same cost. So, in your first code example, you rebuild the index 30000 times, while in the second example, you rebuild the index only once.

By the way, what you are doing could be done even faster using `Graph.Erdos_Renyi(n=10000, m=30000)`.