# Fastest way to add an edge in igraph Python

Tags: python, igraph

With igraph, what's the fastest way to:

1. Pick two random vertices
2. Test if an edge exists between these two vertices
3. If not, add an edge?

I'm iterating a lot through my graphs, and I need every cycle available.

I'm doing this right now:

```
v1, v2 = random.randint(0,nbr_noeuds-1),random.randint(0,nbr_noeuds-1)
while self.state.are_connected(v1, v2):
    v1, v2 = random.randint(0,nbr_noeuds-1),random.randint(0,nbr_noeuds-1)
self.state.add_edge(v1, v2)
```

Comment: I don't use igraph, so I actually don't know. But you could get a minor improvement by "bringing" random.randint to the local namespace. So, say, random_randint = random.randint and then using random_randint(0, nbr_noeuds-1).

Comment: Also, not that this will actually improve speed, just readability, don't compare to True. Your while statement can be "while self.state.are_connected(v1, v2):"

Comment: Adding edges one by one is slow in igraph: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974279/igraph-why-is-add-edge-function-so-slow-ompared-to-add-edges

Comment: You don't specify whether you add edges altogether or do something else between edge adds. In the first case, the link above might be good.

Comment: Every time I add an edge, I run a function with tests, so I need to add only one edge at a time.

Comment: You could also spare some CPU cycles by using `numpy` to generate a large array of random numbers beforehand and then just consume that array. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172131/create-random-list-of-integers-in-python